# move hornetq message from a queue to another without reading it out

Tags: api, queue, jms, hornetq

We have a use case where we would like to get a certain messages in a queue distributed into other queues after we browse the queue and get the message properties. Can that be done with JMS API for hornetq or should we use a JMX client as that seems to be a possible operation in jvisualvm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that org.hornetq.api.jms.management.JMSQueueControl from the HornetQ Management API will do the trick. I was hoping for some generic JMS API that would allow that as well but this will work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand You correctly but if You would like to copy from one queue to another only filtered messages You can use bridge.

http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.3.0.CR2/docs/user-manual/html/core-bridges.html

In bridge configuration You can define which messages should be copied  from one queue to another

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion: I looked into it but the routing logic in our case is quite complex and it really needs to be move internally to the same HornetQ but in a different queue. A better scenario would have been having a topic but for practical reason at the moment is much easier taking the other approach.

Comment: It seems that org.hornetq.api.jms.management.JMSQueueControl from the HornetQ Management API seems it will do the trick. I was hoping for some generic JMS API that would allow that as well but this will work. Thanks for the suggestions.